# Question about string method (fromchararry)

Tags: apex

i want to convert list of integer to string so i used string method (fromCharArray)...but i didn't get the correct value in the string...the code is given below

```
 list<integer>a=new list<integer>{123456};
 string b=string.fromchararray(a);
 system.debug('string'+b);
```

in debug statement i got: string

Comment: What result did you expect? It might be an unprintable character all right, http://dev.networkerror.org/utf8/?start=123450&end=123460show_uni_int=on&show_uni_hex=on&show_html_ent=on&show_raw_hex=on&show_raw_bin=on